# Facing flexbox alignment issue with "w" char

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a very basic structure of divs arranged like a table using flexbox.
Browser - Chrome.

```css
.t {
    contain: size style layout;
}
.ha {
    display: flex;
}

.hc {
    flex: auto;
    border-right: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
    <div class="ha">
        <div class="hc">header1</div>
        <div class="hc">header1</div>
        <div class="hc">header1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ha">
        <div class="hc">a</div>
        <div class="hc">w</div>
        <div class="hc">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ha">
        <div class="hc">a</div>
        <div class="hc">a</div>
        <div class="hc">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is with the unalignment when there is a "w" char in any of the cols.

It works ok in case or other chars, but in case of "w" it disturbs the alignment.
So, I have tried a few ways but nothing worked.

Comment: flex:1 instead of auto

Comment: I think you can either set a font style with a fixed char length, or more easily set `flex:1` instead of flex auto. (As Temani said at the same time :D )